# BradleyTerry2 package in R - Using null hypothesis as reference player

Tags: r, bradleyterry2

I am using the BradleyTerry2 package in R to analyse my data. When using the BTm function to calculate ability scores, the first item in the dataset is removed as a reference, given a score of 0 and then other ability scores are calculated relative to this reference.

Is there a way to use a null hypothesis as a reference, rather than using the first item in the dataset?

This is the code I am using. The "ID" field is player id. This code calculates an ability score for each "Matchup," relative to the first matchup in the dataset.

`BTv1 <- BTm(player1=winner,player2=loser,id="ID",formula=~Matchup+(1|ID),data=btmdata)`

I am trying to test against the null hypothesis that matchup has no effect on match outcomes, but currently I don't know what ability score corresponds to the null hypothesis. I would like to use this null hypothesis as a reference, rather than using the first matchup in the dataset.

For those wanting to reproduce my results, you can find my files on my [university onedrive](https://unsw-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/z5295056_ad_unsw_edu_au/EiIYn9SvaZ1Hrxsxrralc3oBqfTZfEoHVCgrDfNKEQww-w?e=hka24g).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you include some sample data to make this reproducible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @Michael apologies for my delay. I have uploaded the files to reproduce to my [university onedrive](https://unsw-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/z5295056_ad_unsw_edu_au/EiIYn9SvaZ1Hrxsxrralc3oBqfTZfEoHVCgrDfNKEQww-w?e=hka24g).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test the significance of terms in the model for ability using the `anova` function, i.e.

```
anova(BTv1, test = "Chisq")
```

Using the example data and script that you shared, we get the following result:

```
Sequential Wald Tests

Model: binomial, link: logit

Response: NULL

Predictor: ~Characters + (1 | ID)

Terms added sequentially (first to last)

           Statistic Df P(>|Chi|)   
NULL                                
Characters    46.116 26  0.008853 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

---

**Edit**: For the model `BTv2` with log-ability modelled by `~ Matchup+(1|ID)`

Before investigating individual matchups, we should check the significance of the term overall. Unfortunately the `anova()` method for BTm objects doesn't currently work for terms with inestimable parameters, as in this case. So we'll compute this directly:

```
cf <- coef(BTv2)[!is.na(coef(BTv2))]
V <- vcov(BTv2)
ind <- grep("Matchup", names(cf))
chisq <- c(t(cf[ind]) %*% chol2inv(chol(V[ind, ind])) %*% cf[ind])
df <- length(ind)
c(chisq = chisq, df = df)  
#     chisq       df 
#  107.5667 167.0000
```

The Chi-squared statistic is less than the degrees of freedom, so the Matchup term is not significant - the model is over-fitting and it's not a good idea to investigate matchup-specific effects.

All the same, let's look at the model when fitted to the matches involving just 3 of the characters, for illustration.

```
summary(BTv2)$fixef
#                              Estimate Std. Error    z value  Pr(>|z|)
# MatchupCaptainFalcon;Falco -0.1327177  0.3161729 -0.4197632 0.6746585
# MatchupCaptainFalcon;Peach  0.1464518  0.3861823  0.3792297 0.7045173
# MatchupFalco;Peach         -0.4103029  0.3365761 -1.2190496 0.2228254
```

In this case only 3 parameters are estimable, the rest are fixed to zero. Under model BTv2 for players i and j playing characters c and d respectively, we have

logit(p(i playing c beats j playing d))
= log_ability_i - log_ability_j + U_i - U_j
= Matchup_{c;d} - Matchup_{d;c} + U_i - U_j

where U_i and U_j are random player effects. So for players of the same baseline ability we have for example,

logit(p(CaptainFalcon beats Falco)) = -0.1327177 - 0 = -0.1327177
logit(p(Falco beats CaptainFalcon)) = 0 - (-0.1327177) = 0.1327177

So this tells you whether one character is favoured over another in a particular pairwise matchup.

Let's return to the BTv1 model based on all the data. In this model, for players of the same baseline ability we have

logit(p(i playing c beats j playing d)) = log_ability_i - log_ability_j
= Characters_c - Characters_d

The effect for "CharactersBowser" is set to zero, the rest are estimable. So e.g.

```
summary(BTv1)$fixef[c("CharactersFalco", "CharactersPeach"),]
#                 Estimate Std. Error  z value   Pr(>|z|)
# CharactersFalco 2.038925  0.9576332 2.129130 0.03324354
# CharactersPeach 2.119304  0.9508804 2.228781 0.02582845
```

means that

logit(p(Bowser beats Peach)) = 0 - 2.119304 = -2.119304
logit(p(Falcon beats Peach)) = 2.038925 - 2.119304 = -0.080379

So we can still compare characters in a particular matchup. We can use quasi-variances to compare the character effects

```
# add in character with fixed effect set to zero (Bowser)
V <- cbind(XCharactersBowser = 0, rbind(XCharactersBowser = 0, 
vcov(BTv1)))
cf <- c(CharactersBowser = 0, coef(BTv1))
# compute quasi-variances
qv <- qvcalc(V, "XCharacters", estimates = cf,
             labels = sub("Characters", "", names(cf)))
# plot and compare 
# (need to set ylim because some estimates are essentially infinite)
par(mar = c(7, 4, 3, 1)) 
plot(qv, ylim = c(-5, 5))
```

[image: Plot of character effects with comparison intervals based on quasi standard errors.]

See e.g. https://doi.org/10.1093/biomet/91.1.65 for more on quasi-variances.

Comment: This is great! As I understand, this tests the significance of including vs excluding the "Characters" field as a whole, which is very helpful.

I'm looking to do something different with the "Matchup" field though. This field takes the form "Winner character ; loser character". I'm trying to figure out whether one character is favoured over another in a particular pairwise matchup. I expect this will be correlated to character ability scores, with some exceptions.

To this end, I'm looking to investigate individual terms relative to the null hypothesis. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Hi @Heather, I only just saw your edit as I was away for a few weeks over Christmas. This is extremely detailed and I'm pretty sure this is what I was looking for. I'll spend a few days working out exactly what you've done here, but I just wanted to say thank you so much for all the effort you've put into helping me out. You've really gone above and beyond to help me and I'm so grateful.